# Difficulties to update a rate system with location.reload();

Tags: jquery

I have a rate system that I would like update when I select a vote automatically. But it doesn't run... I must do "F5".. I proved to put a location.reload(); but the first time I click, it doesn't run and the second it runs ! The problem is that there is a difference of one click between the counter on the page and the other one on my DB

```
$(function(){
    $('.star').on('mouseover', function(){
        var indice = $('.star').index(this);
        $('.star').removeClass('full');
        for(var i = 0; i<= indice; i++){
            $('.star:eq('+i+')').addClass('full');  
        }
    }); 

    $('.star').on('mouseout', function(){
        $('.star').removeClass('full');
        });

    var average = $('.average').attr('data-average');
    function avaliacao(average){
        average = (Number(average)*20);
        $('.barra .bg').css('width', 0);
        $('.barra .bg').animate({width: average+'%'}, 500);
    }
    avaliacao(average);

    $('.star').on('click', function(){
        var artigoId = $('.artigoDados').attr('data-id');
        var ponto = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('sys/votar.php',{votar: 'sim', artigo: artigoId, ponto: ponto}, function(retorno){
        avaliacao(retorno.average);
        $('p.votos span').html(retorno.votos);

        }, 'jSON');

    });

});
```

**Html**

```
    <?php 

    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notation', 'root', 'root');

    ?>

    <html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/note.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php
        $artigoId = (int)$_GET['artigo'];

        $artigos = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM sys_note WHERE id_recette = ?');
        $artigos->execute(array($artigoId));
        while($row = $artigos->fetchObject()){
        echo '<h1>'.$row->titre_recette.'</h1>';
        $calculo = ($row->pontos == 0) ? 0 : round(($row->pontos/$row->votos), 1);
        echo '<span class="average" data-average="'.$calculo.'"></span>';
        echo '<span class="artigoDados" data-id="'.$row->id_recette.'"></span>';

    ?>

    <div class="barra">
        <span class="bg"></span>
        <div class="estrelas">
        <?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++): ?>
        <span class ="star" id="<?php echo $i;?>">
        <span class="starAbsolute"></span>
        </span>
        <?php endfor;?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="votos"><span><?php echo $row->votos;?></span>votes</p>
    <?php }?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**votar.php**

```
<?php 

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notation', 'root', 'root');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $artigo = (int)$_POST['artigo'];    
    $pontos = $_POST['ponto'];

    $pegaArtigo = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM sys_note WHERE id_recette = ?');
    $pegaArtigo->execute(array($artigo));

    while($row = $pegaArtigo->fetchObject()){
        $votosUpd = $row->votos+1;
        $pontosUpd = $row->pontos+$pontos;
        $average = round(($pontosUpd/$votosUpd), 1);
        $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE sys_note SET votos = ?, pontos = ? WHERE id_recette = ?');
        if($update->execute(array($votosUpd, $pontosUpd, $artigo))){
        die(json_encode(array('average' => $average, 'votos' => $votosUpd)));   

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: So the `location.reload()` really has nothing to do with your question, right? You are just using it as a debugging statement to see if your click handler gets called?

Comment: debugging statement? no, I want use it to show the average on this rate after I clicked on

Comment: you do know that `location.reload()` refreshes the page, right? And if you refresh the page, you will essentially orphan your ajax request and your callbacks will not be called. What you are doing here just doesn't make sense. You don't need a page reload to refresh part of the screen - that's what AJAX does, and you are already doing it. What is the purpose of the page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no need to reload the page, your script will update the html automatically. Remove the reload all together

```
$('.star').on('click', function() {
  var artigoId = $('.artigoDados').attr('data-id');
  var ponto = $(this).attr('id');
  $.post('sys/votar.php', {
    votar: 'sim',
    artigo: artigoId,
    ponto: ponto
  }, function(retorno) {
    avaliacao(retorno.average);
    $('p.votos span').html(retorno.votos);

  }, 'jSON');
});
```

echo the json results

```
while($row = $pegaArtigo->fetchObject()){
    $votosUpd = $row->votos+1;
    $pontosUpd = $row->pontos+$pontos;
    $average = round(($pontosUpd/$votosUpd), 1);
    $update = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE sys_note SET votos = ?, pontos = ? WHERE id_recette = ?');
    if($update->execute(array($votosUpd, $pontosUpd, $artigo))){
        echo json_encode(array('average' => $average, 'votos' => $votosUpd));   

    }

}
```

Comment: It's better because the page is updated but the counter on the page.. doesn't count !

Comment: This will still reload the page before the script finishes.... There will be roughly a < 1ms difference from when the page reloads between your answer and the OP's original code.

Comment: Maybe location.reload is not the right code? I want that when I select a vote, the average been updated and show the new average @mhodges

Comment: @DJ5533 Yeah that is what your AJAX call (`$.post(...)`) should be doing. Remove the `location.reload()` and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing. When I click, nothing happens.. And when I refresh the page, I see the counter actualized ! Why is it not automatic?

Comment: with the way you have the code you shouldnt even have to refresh, it should load the results into `$('p.votos span')` automatically. Try removing the `location.reload();` all together.

Comment: @DJ5533 Well, when you do the page reload, the ajax call still gets sent to the server, so it will still update the database. Then when the page renders after the refresh, it is likely pulling the updated value from the database. What you should do is return the updated value from your `sys/votar.php` action so that you can update the DOM with it without having to perform a page reload.

Comment: @DJ5533 But doing so requires you to return the data in a specific structure. Based on your code, you are accessing the `average` and `votos` properties on the JSON object that (should be) getting returned. In your php code, you need to create a structure that has an `average` and `votos` property on it, put in the proper corresponding data, and then return it to your AJAX call. I think you should read up on how AJAX works, because you can get answers from here all day long, but you will only get deeper and deeper into the weeds and you won't understand any of your code.

Comment: I cancelled location.reload and I add php code (POST EDITED)

Comment: My problem is in the js or php @cesarBielich ? I echo and nothing is echoed

Comment: go to your php file directly with the url and send some test post data and see if the proper results are being echo'd back. Change `$artigo = (int)$_POST['artigo'];` with `$artigo = 'somedata'; ` and so on. This will tell you if its js or php that's the problem.

Comment: When I test like you said me, the result is good. I use firebug and no problem with my php @cesarBielich

Comment: console-reponse of votar.php after I voted @cesarBielich : 
`<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

{"average":2.6,"votos":101}`

Comment: you should not be seeing any html in the response, there should only be json. That could cause your response not to work properly.  Make sure that ONLY json is being returned..

Comment: It's run ! Thanks ! I cancelled the html balise of my votar.php

Comment: glad to hear that